Managing date column with different format
I am trying to convert a pandas dataframe column which is in text format but represents date in mix format to a proper date format. Below is one such example,
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(['0-Jan-00', '8/23/1999'])

Above code generates error.
Is there any method available to directly manage such mix of date format?

Try dateutil  it is very forgiving of different date formats and will work for 90% of the cases.

Thanks. However it would be good if there is a method available within standard python libraries like pandas etc

pd.to_datetime(['0-Jan-00', '8/23/1999'], format='mixed', errors='coerce')

Why the unaccept?

January 0th wouldn't make send because it isn't a real date, but we could try changing to January 1st for a real life example, then use pd.to_datetime with specified arguments.
Try:
pd.to_datetime(['1-Jan-00', '8/23/1999'], format='mixed', errors='coerce')

Output:
DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-01', '1999-08-23'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

If you keep January 0th.
pd.to_datetime(['0-Jan-00', '8/23/1999'], format='mixed', errors='coerce')

Output:
DatetimeIndex(['NaT', '1999-08-23'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)


i got this DatetimeIndex(['NaT', 'NaT'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None) for the  input pd.to_datetime(['1-Jan-00', '8/23/1999'], format='mixed', errors='coerce')
`

@DonFeto It works for me.

i see i had pandas 1.4.4 thus why it gives my NaT i just updated it and everthing works fine thanks .

There is another way to solve your problem using a custom function, but it is slower than the built-in function in to_datetime but it gives a hint as to how such functionality can be made. because the custom function doesn't make use of vectorization, making it slower.
def parse_date(date):
    for fmt in ("%d-%b-%y", "%m/%d/%Y", "%d-%b-%y", "%m/%d/%Y"):
        try:
            yield pd.to_datetime(date, format=fmt)
        except ValueError:
            continue
    return pd.NaT

Here is a test to check the speed of both directions of handling multiple date format.
N = 10000
mixed_dates = np.random.choice(['1-Jan-00', '8/23/1999', '15-Feb-10', '12/12/2012'], N)
df = pd.DataFrame(mixed_dates, columns=['dates'])

# Using the apply and custom function.
start_time = time.time()
df['parsed_dates_custom'] = df['dates'].apply(parse_date)
custom_time = time.time() - start_time

it Takes 0.005984783172607422
start_time = time.time()
pd.to_datetime(df["dates"], format='mixed', errors='coerce')
direct_time = time.time() - start_time

it takes 0.0030856857299804688
Note: format="mixed" doesn't work with old versions of Pandas like 1.4.4 i think it works from 2.0.0
